# html5/bootstrap 3, prevent mobile onscreen keyboard from blocking text input, auto scroll when touchscreen keyboard pops up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

on fb mobile website I've noticed that when text input gains focus and onscreen keyboard pops up, the page will auto scroll to prevent onscreen keyboard from blocking text input, how to do this in bootstrap? on my current bootstrap3 page when text input gets focus keyboard pops up and blocks the text input that i am supposedly typing on

Update 1:
I've noticed that mobile will auto scroll on "regular" and typical html5 inputs, but I've made some sort of custom "fixed" (style="position:absolute;etc etc") context menu and noticed browser won't autoscroll on it (e.g standard modals when getting inputs will autoscroll, but my context menus which are actually heavily modified modals shown via $('#context').show(); they don't work there)

Comment: What mobile browser are you trying that on? I've just tried a Bootstrap site of mine on Chrome for Android and it moved correctly. Firefox for Android also moved but not quite enough (a few pixels of the bottom of my text box was obscured).

Comment: I used google chrome